# Shifting the turtles towards a direction that takes into account the continuity of the roads

Tags: gis, netlogo

My model simulates vehicular traffic on a GIS map (raster file). The route of the turtles is based on the minimum distance between the current position and the target. How do I calculate the minimum route taking into account the discontinuity of the roads? I am attaching an image as an example of the problem encountered and the procedure for calculating the minimum distance.

The turtle must go from "A" to "B", but it hangs on the patch closest to the target as the crow flies.

[image]

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    direzione-turtles
    face direzione ;aggiunto
    ifelse  next-patch != nobody
    [
      face next-patch
      fd 1 ask patch-here [set done? true]]
    [set other-choices neighbors with [strada > 0 and stato <= 4 ]
      move-to one-of other-choices ;al posto di face
      fd 1]]
  tick
end

to-report next-patch
  if direzione = casa and (member? patch-here [neighbors] of casa) [
    set direzione ufficio
  ]
  if direzione = ufficio and (member? patch-here [neighbors] of ufficio) [
    set direzione casa
  ]
  set choices neighbors with [done? = false and strada > 0 and stato >= 1 and stato <= 4]
  set choice min-one-of choices [distance [direzione] of myself]
  report choice
end
```

Comment: One way to approach this problem is to create (invisible) turtles at each intersection and have links connect these turtles. Then you can use the network shortest distance to calculate how to get from one point to another. I think there is an example of this in the NetLogo models library, but I don't have access to check at the moment.

Comment: I think it's a good procedure, but my environment is too large (X: 673, Y: 482) and too fragmented (raster map with 10 pixels of resolution). Thanks for your availability.